# Modbus TCP together with MQTT over same ethernet

Tags: ethernet, modbus, mqtt, ethernet-shield

I'm currently in a planning phase for a project.
I want to read some sensor data over Modbus TCP, do some simple calculations on the Arduino and publish the results over MQTT. Which means I have 2 RJ-45s and two different protocols.

Given a Arduino Mega with an Ethernet shield.
Does it work if I simply add a network switch and connect the sensor and an internet router to it, and use both protocols in parallel?
Or are there any problems running such a thing on only one Arduino?

Comment: don't underestimate Arduino. here are the ino files of Arduino sketch for my main project: https://github.com/jandrassy/Regulator#sketch it runs on ATmega1284p boaard. and a simpler Modbus TCP project with web server https://github.com/jandrassy/IsgModbusTcpSG which runs on Nano Every

Answer (score 1):

> Does it work if I simply add a network switch and connect the sensor and an internet router to it, and use both protocols in parallel?

Kind of, yes. You just connect both the MODBUS device and the Arduino to the network provided by the router. The Arduino is just a normal network device - the IP address for it allocated by the router, as is the MODBUS device.

Any device can communicate with any other device in a network.